# Powershell: How to request user authentication to continue

Tags: powershell, authentication

My Powershell script has some features/functions implemented, but there are some features that I want to restrict to some users.

In order to allow the current user or a different user to select such restricted features from the menu, I am looking for a way to require user authentication from Windows to continue. How could I do that? How the `UserAuthentication` function below should be like?

Code:

```
$feature = Read-Host 'Select the feature by typing the number [1 - 2]'

switch ($feature)
{  
    1
    {
        write-output "This feature any user can reach"
    }
    2
    {
        $user = Read-Host "This feature only some user can reach and requires authentication. Entry your username to proceed"
        $allowedUsers = "user1", "user2"

        if($allowedUsers.contains($user))
        {
            write-output "This feature the user $user can reach. Please authenticate to continue"  
            if((UserAuthentication $user) -eq $true)
            {
                write-output "$user successfully authenticated"
            }
            else
            {
                write-output "$user unsuccessful authenticated"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            write-output "This feature the user $user cannot reach"
        }
    }
}

function UserAuthentication($user)
{
    return $true #May return 'True' if successfully authenticated or 'False' if not.
}
```

Comment: Depends on the type of user - Active Directory users, local accounts, AAD accounts, something else?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, sorry but how can I check that?

Comment: I mean - you'll know that better than any of us? Who is the audience for this script/application, and where/how do you intend to deploy it?

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for when your users are member of an AD domain**

I have changed the function name `UserAuthentication` to `Get-Authentication` to comply with the [Verb-Noun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/learning-powershell-names) function naming convention in PowerShell.

```
# helper function test if a username/password combination is valid.
# if valid, the username entered in the box is returned.
function Get-Authentication {
    $Credentials = Get-Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" -Message "Please authenticate to continue" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($Credentials) {
        $UserName = $Credentials.UserName
        $Password = $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password   # --> plain-text password
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
        $ds = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext Domain
        if ($ds.ValidateCredentials($UserName, $Password)) {
            # return the username entered
            $UserName
        }
    }
}

# your code here

# fill in the SamAccountNames of allowed users for this feature
$allowedUsers = 'samaccountname','of', 'users', 'that', 'are', 'allowed', 'to', 'use', 'feature 2'

$feature = Read-Host 'Select the feature by typing the number [1 - 2]'
switch ($feature) {  
    '1' { Write-Output "This feature any user can reach" }
    '2' { 
        $user = Get-Authentication
        if ($null -ne $user -and $allowedUsers -contains $user) {
            Write-Output "User $user is allowed for this feature"
        }
        else {
            Write-Output "This feature the user cannot reach"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Theo, I need it in a way that allows checking a different user also, instead of checking only who is currently logged.

Comment: @CleberMarques I have put new code to authenticate a user. This is for users in an AD domain.